# Is there a simple way to swap staged and non-staged Git content?

Tags: git

Sometimes while working on something I'll find something else which needs fixing first. At this point I might have already staged part of that file and some other files (new and tracked) and I want to swap out the current staging for the non-staged content. Is there some way to do this?

Example session:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmp.7HssIqQ2qT/.git/
$ echo foo > foo
$ echo bar > bar
$ git add .
$ git commit --message="Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) c6db082] Initial commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 bar
 create mode 100644 foo
$ echo foo2 > foo
$ echo baz > baz
$ git add foo baz
$ echo foo3 >> foo
$ echo bar2 > bar
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   baz
    modified:   foo

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   bar
    modified:   foo
```

Basically, how do I swap the above changes to be committed and changes not staged for commit, bearing in mind that only *part* of the changes to "foo" have been staged? The simplest I can think of so far is creating two stashes and popping them in reverse order, but it doesn't work very well:

```
$ git stash --include-untracked --keep-index
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 3dba6aa Initial commit
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   baz
    modified:   foo
$ git stash --include-untracked
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git stash pop stash@{1}
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   baz

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   bar
    modified:   foo

Dropped stash@{1} (6fb8f81bdb2dc9fc1f218e7c25e74ad32c01fc0e)
```

Somehow baz is popped as part of the *oldest* stash, so the state is already messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Note: before I dive into the answer below, I have two notes:

- You might be better off using `git worktree add` and working in two branches, or just committing now and then rearranging later.  If you commit now, you can use `git rebase -i` later to swap the order of the commits.  This lets you achieve more elegantly, I think, what the patches in the next bullet point will do.  (But you do have to remember to rebase.)
- The trick below uses full snapshots and you might be thinking in terms of differences, in which case, the two `git read-tree`s may not get what you want.  Try it out and see if it's what you want, or not.  If that's *not* what you want, consider making two patches via `git diff --cached` and then `git diff`, saving both of those, doing a hard reset, and then applying each of the two patches in sequence with a `git add; git commit` between them.  Note that this may well see merge conflicts!

In any case, I don't think there is anything *particularly* elegant, but `git stash`—even without `--keep-index`—gets you, perhaps, the commits you'd like.  (Note: I recommend not using `--include-untracked`.)

Remember that a commit *is* (or rather, contains) a full snapshot of *every* file, or more specifically, every file that was in the index at the time you made the commit.  Meanwhile, what's in the index is a full copy of *every* file.  What's in your work-tree is up to you; Git will merely either copy a file from your work-tree into the index (`git add`) or copy from the index to your work-tree (`git restore` in 2.23 and later).<sup>1</sup>

Meanwhile, a simple `git commit` makes a new commit from whatever is in your index *right now.*  If that matches what is in `HEAD` you need to add a flag,<sup>2</sup> but that's what it does.  Compare this with `git stash`, which makes *two or three* commits.  The first of these commits is made from the index as usual, except that it's not on *any* branch.  The second of these commits is made by copying your currently-tracked work-tree files—those that are in the index—into the index, so that the second commit contains your tracked work-tree files.  The third commit, if it exists,<sup>3</sup> contains the work-tree files that were not in the second commit (and which have subsequently been deleted).  We can call the first two commits `I` and `W`, and [the `git-stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) does exactly that—follow the link and read the DISCUSSION section.

Hence, running `git stash` creates two commits, each of which holds the files you'd like to now have in either your work-tree (the `I` commit) or the index (the `W` commit).  So we can now do that, using either the new `git restore` command for updating the work-tree and then `git read-tree` to fill in the index, or using two separate `git read-tree` commands (in any version of Git):

```
git stash                  # make commits I and W which are stash^2 and stash
git read-tree -mu stash^2  # copy I commit to index and work-tree
git read-tree stash        # copy W commit to index, leaving work-tree untouched
```

after which we can drop the stash with `git stash drop` (though I won't here).

The one part that is slightly tricky here is that `baz`, which is new, *is* in the `W` commit and hence appears in the `changes staged for commit` section.  Hence:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   bar
    new file:   baz
    modified:   foo

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   bar
    modified:   foo
```

If you don't want this—if you want the index not to have these new files—simply run `git rm --cached` on them:

```
$ git rm --cached baz
rm 'baz'
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   bar
    modified:   foo

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   bar
    modified:   foo

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    baz
```

Note that removing the new file from the index converts it, by definition, to an untracked file.

(Use `git diff --cached`, or `git diff --staged` if you like that spelling better, to see what is now staged.)

---

I'm deliberately glossing over / ignoring what `git checkout` or `git switch` does normally, which involves copying a commit to *both* the index *and* your work-tree, here, so as to focus on the concept that we normally do one of these:

```
commit -> index                # e.g., git reset --mixed
          index -> work-tree   # e.g., git checkout-index / git restore
          index <- work-tree   # e.g., git add
```

The `git restore` command is capable of doing `commit -> work-tree` while completely bypassing—leaving unchanged—the index, which no earlier command can do.  We can approximate it with `git show HEAD:path/to/file > path/to/file`, which is more flexible—we do not have to use the *same* path twice—but depends on redirection, which is why we have to give the path twice.

<sup>2</sup>This flag is spelled `--allow-empty`, but the index is probably not actually *empty*.  It is probably full of files.  It's just that the files match those in the `HEAD` commit, so that the *difference* is empty.

<sup>3</sup>The third commit exists if and only if you use `-u` or `-a` or their longer spellings, `--include-untracked` or `--all`.

Comment: Would this work if only part of baz was in the index? I'm basically looking for a universally applicable "swap index and working tree" command. Also, holy moley, thanks for looking into this in such depth!

Comment: "If only part of baz was in the index" - the index contains a *copy of the file*. Whatever is in that copy, that's what's in the index. It's not a difference. That's the key difference between commits (including stashes) and patches: commits are snapshots, patches are diffs.

Comment: What I mean is I can add only part of a file, at which point only part of that file is in the index. At least that's what `git status` is showing me: the file is listed *both* in "to be committed" and "not staged". So *something* must contain only part of the file, and that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: The index holds a copy of the file in the state it had when you ran `git add` on it. The work-tree holds the updated file. In this case these are two identical copies of `baz`, each with one line. But there are three copies of `foo`: the frozen one in `HEAD` with one line `foo`, the one in the index with two lines `foo` and `foo2`, and your work-tree copy with the one line `foo3`.

Comment: Isn't "The index holds a copy of the file in the state it had when you ran git add on it" and "these are two identical copies of baz" a contradiction? If there are two *identical* copies of baz, what is the third thing that holds the difference between what is about to be committed and what is in the working tree? Since it is possible to commit part of a new file, something *must* be holding the file when it was added.

Comment: The two copies of baz are identical because baz didn't change between create-and-`git-add` and the subsequent modifications to the work-tree. The two uncommitted copies of `foo` are not identical.

Comment: I think we might be responding past each other. If I `echo foo > new && git add new && echo bar >> new` then `git diff --cached` shows the "foo" line is staged (aka. "in the index") and `git diff` shows the "bar" line is not staged. Are you saying that this difference is not in the index?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The *difference* isn't in the index: the index contains a one line file reading `foo`, while the work-tree contains a two-line file reading `foo` and then `bar`. The *difference* is computed dynamically upon request from these two copies of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... probably there is some other *more elegant* way to do it but you could do it like this:

```
# save content from index into a temp file
git show :0:path-to-file > file-from-index
# if content is in file-from-index, continue with the recipe
# save file from working tree into index
git add path-to-file
# move file as you saved from index into the right working tree path
mv file-from-index path-to-file
```

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to answer the question as asked,

first step is prep work, and leaves you with just the staged changes in the work tree:

```
git stash -k
```

After that, to swap to the just-the-unstaged-changes content,

```
git read-tree -um @; git cherry-pick -nm2 stash
```

and to swap to the just-the-staged-changes content,

```
git read-tree -um stash^2
```

and to get back to the stashed state regardless of what horrors you've visited on your current index and work tree,

```
git read-tree -um stash
git stash drop
```

You might need to use `--reset -u` rather -than -um` if there are potential conflicts in the updates.

Comment: I don't really want to involve another branch or create any commits (yet), I just want to swap the contents of the staging area and the non-staged contents.

Comment: Ah. Sorry for assuming the extra steps, better now?